# How add link href in product Opencart?

Tags: php, opencart

I Beginner for Opencart, I try add some product in my home website.
I check from category/product.php in Store Front, every product have link by category(linkweb/Computer/Notebook/product)

When i check from category.tpl It's use `<a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>">`

In Controller for product :

```
'href' => $this->url->link('product/product', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '&product_id=' . $result['product_id'])
```

But I don't know where the code came from `if (isset($this->request->get['path'])) {` (already check in view & model)

How i can add request `$this->request->get['path']` in my code for make href ??

I would appreciate any answers or comments.

Comment: http://wiki.opencarthelp.com/doku.php?id=method_request_get

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add particular product(s) into the Home page of your shop, then there is "Featured" module for this purpose. Just add products there and put it into the Home Layout.